# matplotlib Event Listeners Not Funcitoning In PyQT Widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a library of draggable matplotlib objects that I'm trying to utilize with a PyQt5 GUI. The objects' [event listeners](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) function correctly in a standalone matplotlib figure window but do not function when the figure is embedded in a QT widget. Both plots render correctly and there are no error messages when I try to drag the patch in the QT widget.

Object MCVE:

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches

class _DragObj:
    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.parentcanvas = ax.figure.canvas
        self.parentax = ax

        self.clickpress = self.parentcanvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_click)
        self.clicked = False

    def on_click(self, event):
        if event.inaxes != self.parentax: return

        self.mousemotion = self.parentcanvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)
        self.clickrelease = self.parentcanvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_release)

        self.clickx = event.xdata  
        self.clicky = event.ydata

        self.clicked = True

    def on_release(self, event):
        self.clicked = False
        self.disconnect()

    def disconnect(self):
        self.parentcanvas.mpl_disconnect(self.mousemotion)
        self.parentcanvas.mpl_disconnect(self.clickrelease)
        self.parentcanvas.draw()

    def stopdrag(self):
        self.myobj.set_url('')
        self.parentcanvas.mpl_disconnect(self.clickpress)

class _DragPatch(_DragObj):
    def __init__(self, ax, xy):
        super().__init__(ax)

        self.oldxy = xy

    def on_motion(self, event):
        if not self.clicked: return
        if event.inaxes != self.parentax: return

        oldx, oldy = self.oldxy
        dx = event.xdata - self.clickx
        dy = event.ydata - self.clicky
        newxy = [oldx + dx, oldy + dy]
        self.myobj.xy = newxy

        self.parentcanvas.draw()

    def on_release(self, event):
        self.clicked = False
        self.oldxy = self.myobj.xy

        self.disconnect()

class DragRectangle(_DragPatch):
    def __init__(self, ax, xy, width, height, angle=0.0, **kwargs):
        self.myobj = patches.Rectangle(xy, width, height, angle, **kwargs)
        ax.add_artist(self.myobj)

        super().__init__(ax, xy)
```

The functioning matplotlib example:

```
import minidrag
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rect = minidrag.DragRectangle(ax, (0, 0), 2, 1)

ax.set_xlim(-5, 5)
ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)

plt.show()
```

The nonfunctional PyQT example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as QtW
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import minidrag

class windowGUI(QtW.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set up figure
        width_px = 800
        height_px = 600

        rect = QtW.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
        screenrez = (rect.width(), rect.height())
        left_px = (screenrez[0] - width_px)/2
        top_px = (screenrez[1] - height_px)/2
        self.setGeometry(left_px, top_px, width_px, height_px)
        self.canvas = PlotCanvas()

        layout = QtW.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self))
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):
        fig = Figure(frameon=False)
        super().__init__(fig)
        super().setSizePolicy(QtW.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtW.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        super().updateGeometry()

        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        rect = minidrag.DragRectangle(ax, (0, 0), 2, 1)

        ax.set_xlim(-5, 5)
        ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)

app = QtW.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = windowGUI()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm using Python 3.6.0, matplotlib (2.0.0), and PyQt5 (5.8)

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried implementing `def dragEnterEvent(self, event): event.acceptProposedAction()` for all the _embedding_ `QWidget`s? Otherwise the event can't propagate to the embedded widget. Btw you might need to do the same for `dropEvent`. See [QWidget.dragEnterEvent](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#dragEnterEvent).

Comment: Because AFAIK drag events are ignored by default. Maybe it is sufficient to set [`setAcceptDrops(True)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setAcceptDrops) (at least the corresponding property is `False` by default; see [the C++ docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#acceptDrops-prop)). You might also want to read the [C++ drag & drop docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) for more information on how drag & drop works within Qt (the pyqt references sometimes are a bit sparse when it comes to more specific topics).

Comment: It's not a drag & drop. Neither proposed solution works.

Comment: Yes you are right, the dragging only occurs within the matplotlib figure so qt shouldn't interfere here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the problem are not drag events but instead your `minidrag.DragRectangle` instance just being garbage collected (while the canvas remains showing the rectangle at its original position).

As a fix you can set the rectangle as an instance variable:

```
self.rect = minidrag.DragRectangle(ax, (0, 0), 2, 1)
```

(Tested with Python2.7 and PyQt4.)

Comment: oh, that's annoying :)