# Uniting 2 sets works not the way I expected in python

Tags: python, set, bitwise-or

I have a code as below:

```
v={'B', 'C', 'a', 'f', 'g', 'c', 'd'}
u=v
t={'B', 'C','H'}
u|=t
print v,u
```

It gives this result:

```
set(['a', 'C', 'B', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'H', 'c']) set(['a', 'C', 'B', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'H', 'c'])
```

Why on Earth would line 4 change v?? I only expect u to change. I would understand if I would write v=u, but not other way.

Comment: Take a look at [Python's Passing by References](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42908412/674039).  After `u = v`, the u and v are just "nametags" attached to the same identical object.  Any changes to that object will be reflected on all references to it.

Comment: `u=v` are referring the same object so use `u=v[:]` or `u=v.copy()`

Comment: From Python Doc.

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. 

So u = v just means the variable u refers to the same object as v.
Thus, whenever you change u, you change v too.

Comment: You can use frozensets if you don't need the mutability. They're also hashable, so you can have sets of sets.